# Inserting data to a Database Visual Studio

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to insert data into a database using service-based Database I am using Visual Studio 2010. I have created the table but it doesn't work here is my code:
I would appreciate if you have suggestion of code how to insert to a database.

```
public void AddAnimal(int animalID, string name, double age, string category, string gender, string extraAnimalInfo)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBAccessLayer.Properties.Settings.Default.AnimalDBConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO AnimalTable VALUES(@AnimalID, @Name, @Age, @Category, @Gender, @ExtraAnimalInfo)", con))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Here 4");
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("AnimalID", animalID));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", name));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Age", age));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Category", category));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Gender", gender));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ExtraAnimalInfo", extraAnimalInfo));
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not insert.");
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE1:**
When I insert the data into the database the rows are affected but When I open the database table from the Server Explorer nothing have changed.

---

When I insert the data into the database the rows are affected but When I open the database table from the Server Explorer I don't see any changes.

Comment: Define "isn't working".  Throws an Exception?  Which exception?  What message is associated with that exception?

Comment: As per what Eric J. says, change your `Console.WriteLine("Could not insert.");` to `Console.WriteLine("Could not insert: " + ex);` and you'll get some useful information you or we can use to diagnose what is going on.

Comment: When I insert the data into the database the rows are affected but When I open the database table from the Server Explorer nothing have changed.

Comment: Check your connection string (`Console.WriteLine(DBAccessLayer.Properties.Settings.Default.AnimalDBConnectionString);` at the start of the method) versus the connection information for the server/database you're viewing in Server Explorer. Sounds like there's an environment mismatch here.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. For me, it was the connection string. Originally I had

"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + "|DataDirectory|pr.mdf;" + "Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

When I replaced |DataDirectory| with the full path to the DB (right click on the DB in the solution explore, click properties and then use the full path). It worked. It seams as though there are a couple of different DB copies...i.e. there is a copy of it in the \bin\Debug\ folder.

Comment: I came here from google searching for the same solution. It solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A sql insert command requires the column names before the values keyword.

INSERT INTO AnimalTable (AnimalID, Name,Age,Category,Gender,ExtraAniamlInfo) VALUES(@AnimalID, @Name, @Age, @Category, @Gender, @ExtraAnimalInfo)

Comment: its not required if you specify every column and in the same order as they appear in the table. At least for Oracle and some other.s

Comment: Same is true for SQL Server